# What is the proper architecture for requesting a document vs. document details in a REST API?

Tags: node.js, rest

I'm designing a REST API using NodeJS and Express for managing different types of documents (txt, pdf, doc, etc). The document model is something like:

```
   {
   id,
   category,
   name,
   path,
   tags,
   etc.. 
   }
```

I currently have a route to GET a single document.
`/documents/:id`
This route serves up the actual document. I would love some guidance on the proper way to serve up the document details (i.e. the name, category, etc). Should I use a different URL? Send details in headers? Use response.format? Make the client specify via query?

Edit: I should clarify that the documents will be stored on the server filesystem and will not be directly accessible by any client.

Comment: If you are storing lots of documents, you'll want to use cloud storage, like AWS S3 buckets. You can use the AWS-SDK to upload documents there. You will then get a URL, which you could store in your database, with the document id, category, etc.

Comment: @MattKuhns thanks. I edited to mention the storage will be server filesystem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the document details are coming from a different source, the most straightforward way is to set up a different endpoint, `/document-details/:id`.

Otherwise, if a document can be stringified into a JSON, you could nest both in the same response:

```
{
  document: {},
  details: {
    category,
    name,
    path,
    tags
  }
}
```

I would recommend against sending any detail about document in the HTTP header, those are usually used to send the details about the response itself.